# Are there studies that shows significant link between repetitive heading and brain injuries?

Tags: football, injuries

Are there studies that shows significant link between repetitive heading and brain injuries?

Comment: Ram, any chances you could make this post a Q&A, because I think it is a Q&A. I'm trying to clear the unanswered tab for football tag and can't imagine a better answer to this question than the one provided below the horizontal bar in this question.

Comment: @gdrt OK, I will make it a Q&A and let's see responses to it. What happened was I tried searching for answer of this question but couldn't write one so added everything to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Issue of link between repetitive headers and dementia has been bought up after [retirement of striker Kevin Doyle over concussion problems](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/football/2017/09/28/kevin-doyle-retires-due-health-worries-persistent-headaches/) but all started by the [death of Spurs legend Danny Blanchflower from Alzheimer’s disease](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4961714/Calls-parliamentary-inquiry-FA-dementia-links.html).

Former West Brom and England striker Jeff Astle died aged 59 in 2002 and it was found that [repeatedly heading heavier balls had caused the dementia](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/parliamentary-inquiry-call-links-between-11308796) which led to his death.

These articles [1st](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/parliamentary-inquiry-call-links-between-11308796), [2nd](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4961714/Calls-parliamentary-inquiry-FA-dementia-links.html) suggest FA were warned 22 years ago about dangers of heading footballs but FA refused it saying there is no connection back then.

> Baroness Elaine Murphy said she wrote to the FA in 1995 about the dangers posed to players in the sport, but claims the footballing body was 'very short and refuted any such association could exist'.

Recently [FA announced to fund study of dementia among footballers](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-4371782/FA-announce-fund-study-dementia-football.html) and [Uefa also has commissioned a research project that will examine the links between dementia and playing football](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/38990953).

[This study](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/news-and-comment/dementia-in-football-heading-fa-pfa-footballers-head-injury-a7580496.html) mentions, dementia among retired footballers may be connected to repeated head ‘impacts’, caused by collisions and thousands of headers.

> The study included post-mortem examinations on six players who suffered dementia, which reveal that all of them had suffered from a tearing to a brain membrane consistent with chronic, repetitive head impacts from playing football.

This study was initiated on 1980, and was done on 14 men with dementia and a significant history of playing football, monitoring them over time and carrying out post-mortem studies in six cases. So, *not sure if this study is significant enough*.

Other articles that might be of interest, [1st](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/news-and-comment/nobby-stiles-manchester-united-england-pfa-fa-alzheimers-dementia-a7532336.html), [2nd](http://www.goal.com/en/news/worlds-leading-concussion-expert-warns-football-must-change/17boliqwam6ls1rou69ikj5iev), and [3rd](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/30303721).